# a consequence that implies from continuity of a function

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation, riemann-surfaces

In this theorem for proving claim (a) why it said that there exist $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $A([0, \epsilon_0]×I)$  is subset of U. Shouldn't we say $[0, \epsilon_0)$ instead of that because this is open in [0,1] , and the proof would be easier?[image]

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: @Cornman this is from Forster ’s riemann surfaces book.